# How to manage Bestseller module in OpenCart 2.0 +

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I want to add a bestseller product to my home page. In the admin panel there is a bestseller module that I enabled and set to my home page layout, but I can not see any bestseller products. How can I enable or show them on page?

Can anybody tell me how to enable it for products?

Comment: Viral, bestseller product module only display product which are sold and his status is complete order then it will automatically display on the home page.

Comment: Vipul Jethva : Thank u sirji.....